# Azure Kubernetes - Jaeger UI is not showing the Service deployed as a part of ISTIO?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, azure-aks, jaeger

I have used the following configuration to setup the Istio

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istio-control-plane
spec:
  # Use the default profile as the base
  # More details at: https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/
  profile: default
  # Enable the addons that we will want to use
  addonComponents:
    grafana:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
    tracing:
      enabled: true
    kiali:
      enabled: true
  values:
    global:
      # Ensure that the Istio pods are only scheduled to run on Linux nodes
      defaultNodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kiali:
      dashboard:
        auth:
          strategy: anonymous
  components:
    egressGateways:
    - name: istio-egressgateway
      enabled: true
EOF
```

and exposed the jaeger-query service as mentioned below

```
kubectl expose service jaeger-query  --type=LoadBalancer --name=jaeger-query-svc --namespace istio-system
kubectl get svc jaeger-query-svc -n istio-system -o json
export JAEGER_URL=$(kubectl get svc jaeger-query-svc -n istio-system  -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0]['hostname','ip']}"):$(kubectl get svc jaeger-query-svc -n istio-system -o 'jsonpath={.spec.ports[0].port}')
echo http://${JAEGER_URL}
curl http://${JAEGER_URL}
```

I couldn't see the below deployed application in Jaeger

[image]

and have deployed the application as mentioned below

```
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: stenote/nginx-hostname
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
EOF

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: public-gateway
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: "${KEY_CERT2_NAME}"
    hosts:
    - web.zaalion.com
EOF


cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  hosts:
    - web.zaalion.com
  gateways:
    - public-gateway
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: web.akv2k8s-test.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 80
EOF
```

I could access the service as shown below

```
export EXTERNAL_IP=$(kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')

curl -v --resolve web.zaalion.com:443:$EXTERNAL_IP --cacert cert2.crt https://web.zaalion.com
```

I do know why the service is not listed in the Jaeger UI?

Comment: According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/jaeger/#generating-traces-using-the-bookinfo-sample) `To see trace data, you must send requests to your service. The number of requests depends on Istio’s sampling rate. You set this rate when you install Istio. The default sampling rate is 1%. You need to send at least 100 requests before the first trace is visible.` Could you try to send at least 100 requests and check if it works?

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there any way to reduce this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/jaeger/#generating-traces-using-the-bookinfo-sample)

> To see trace data, you must send requests to your service. The number of requests depends on Istio’s sampling rate. You set this rate when you install Istio. The default sampling rate is 1%. You need to send at least 100 requests before the first trace is visible. Could you try to send at least 100 requests and check if it works?

If you wan't to change the default sampling rate then there is istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/configurability/#customizing-trace-sampling) about that.

> **Customizing Trace sampling**
>
> The sampling rate option can be used to control what percentage of requests get reported to your tracing system. This should be configured depending upon your traffic in the mesh and the amount of tracing data you want to collect. The default rate is 1%.
>
> To modify the default random sampling to 50, add the following option to your tracing.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  meshConfig:
    defaultConfig:
      tracing:
        sampling: 50
```

> The sampling rate should be in the range of 0.0 to 100.0 with a precision of 0.01. For example, to trace 5 requests out of every 10000, use 0.05 as the value here.